# All apps downloaded from Office Store require username and password to view

Tags: 2013, web-part, authentication

I've successfully setup Sharepoint's Office Store, and have begun testing some of the app that can be downloaded for Sharepoint from the App Store. These apps download successful and function properly, however the webparts for these apps require credentials before they are displayed and it does this for each Office App webpart on the page (i.e if there are 3 downloaded webparts on the page, you need to enter your credentials three times for all to be displayed). I've also tried making these webparts available to the everyone group to see if that'd resolve my problem but still prompts me for credentials. Any ideas of how I can get these webparts to read the users credentials automatically like the rest of my Sharepoint site?

Kevin